# MySQL - SELECT query order by itself

Tags: mysql, sql

Help me please. I have table:

```
id|count
1 |1
1 |3
2 |1
2 |2
3 |1
3 |2
```

I need to select ids with `count` (the column) of 1 and 2 for the same `id`:

```
id
2
3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
select id
from t
where count in (1, 2)
group by id
having count(*) = 2;
```

Comment: I'd do `having count(distinct count) = 2`, just in case.

Comment: or `having count(*) >= 2;` This is also fine than using a `distinct`.

Comment: @Ullas . . . That is not the same.  The data could (I suppose) have three rows with "1"s.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : Then if, `id=2` has `count` column value `2` twice, then `count(*)` is definitely more than 2. That case result set wont have `2`.

Comment: @Ullas . . . You are confused by the column name.  The OP is referring to the values in the column, not to a count generated in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this

```
select  t1.id
from    myTable t1
join    myTable t2
on      t1.id = t2.id
where   t1.count = 1 and t2.count = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `INTERSECT` to find the id's with both 1 and 2:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE count = 1
INTERSECT
SELECT id FROM table WHERE count = 2
```

**EDIT:** Oops, does MySQL support `INTERSECT`?

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP BY Clause :

```
 SELECT DISTINCT id FROM Your_Table 
 WHERE [count] IN (1, 2)
 GROUP BY id 
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

Comment: This will retrieve even `1` in the result set.

Comment: Sorry,I didn't see count 1 and 3.I updated my post.Thanks Ullas.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select id 
 FROM TABLE_NAME  
 WHERE count = 1 
 INTERSECT 
 Select id
 FROM TABLE_NAME 
 WHERE count = 2;
```

That should work. Here is a link for using of intersect https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-intersect-clause.htm